# ignoredYellowBox warnings doesn't take effect if the warning contain quotation mark (') in react-native

Tags: react-native

In `react-native`, one can add prefix strings to `console.ignoredYellowBox` to disallow some specific warnings to show up in the phone but it doesn't seem to work if the warning has some quotation mark in it. For e.g., one of the warnings that I want to disable is

```
"Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop 'date' of type 'Number' supplied to 'RCTDatePicker', expected instance of 'Date'"
```

So, I added below as one of the strings in the `console.ignoredYellowBox` array

```
"Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop 'date' of type 'Number' supplied to 'RCTDatePicker'"
```

But I still see the warning. If I add just `"Warning: Failed propType"`, I don't see the warning but it also disables some other warnings that are rather helpful. For e.g., it also disabled the warning that is shown if there is a typo in some flexbox property. So, I wanted to specifically ignore the warnings. Has anybody else seen this behavior? I tried to check the `react-native` code where warnings are ignored and it looks good but I am not a JS expert.